# How to synchronize or lock upon variables in Java?

Tags: java, synchronization

Let me use this small and simple sample:

```
class Sample {
    private String msg = null;

    public void newmsg(String x){
        msg = x;
    }

    public String getmsg(){
        String temp = msg;
        msg = null;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Let's assume the function `newmsg()` is called by other threads that I don't have access to.

I want to use the synchonize method to guarantee that the string `msg` is only used by one function per time. In other words, function `newmsg()` cannot run at the same time as `getmsg()`.

Comment: Are you asking how to use "synchronized" keyword in Java? A simple google search comes back with a lot of useful hits including this one http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Btw, it would be much better to call our getmsg() method something like popmsg() or consumemsg() since it modifies the class

Answer (score 184, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
class Sample {
    private String message = null;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void newMessage(String x) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            message = x;
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            String temp = message;
            message = null;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I *didn't* either make the methods themselves synchronized or synchronize on `this`. I firmly believe that it's a good idea to only acquire locks on objects which only your code has access to, unless you're *deliberately* exposing the lock. It makes it a lot easier to reassure yourself that nothing else is going to acquire locks in a different order to your code, etc.

Comment: what is the difference between set the synchronize on function or create this lock ?

Comment: +1 Good and sensitive but beware of over-engineering. Maybe this class is just a message dispatcher so instantiating a lock object is just wasteful. Don't exaggerate.

Comment: @Giacomo: I like my code to be readable, and designed so that I can reason about it. That's doubly important when multi-threading is involved. It's not exaggerating to say that this is the kind of code I'd almost *always* use. As for being *wasteful*... how often would you expect this waste to be significant?

Comment: @Jon: very little, indeed. However I too like my code to be readable and on my personal opinion (I might be wrong) using another field when it's not necessary (and we really don't know if it is) makes stuff less readable. However, good answer.

Comment: @Giacomo: The point is that it's obvious that you're locking on something no-one else can. That seems reasonably straight-forward to reason about: you read the code, and you're done. Now consider your example: how do you know what *might* synchronize on your object? How can you understand the locking behaviour? You have to read *all* the code involved. I'd therefore say it's less readable if you're actually bothered by the behaviour being correct. Frankly I believe it was a mistake to allow *all* objects to be locked in Java. (A mistake .NET copied, unfortunately.)

Comment: What about the visibility on `message`?  With `message` missing the `volatile` modifier, even with the atomic access on lock one thread may not see the changes the other thread(s) have made to `message`.

Comment: @StuThompson: I believe they will, because of the interaction `synchronized` has with the memory model.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ah, ok.  Had to go re-read the 133 FAQ...had forgotten about the monitor release memory writing, thread cache invalidating behaviors.  Thanks.

Comment: Will this solution help prevent the owner thread of `Sample`'s object to modify msg if the intrinsic lock on `lock` variable defined here is obtained by another thread?

Comment: @JonSkeet what I mean by that is the thread that initialized the object of `Sample`'s class which we want to modify.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal: That thread has no special ownership of it - it would need to acquire the monitor associated with `lock` just like any other thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, I was told something else here in the first comment to my question and that's what raised the confusion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217897/does-synchronize-keyword-prevent-a-thread-from-using-its-own-variable-while-lock

Comment: @AkashAggarwal: No, I don't think you were given a different message. You need to differentiate between "ability to change state" (which just depends on whether or not your code has access to the field) and "ability to acquire a monitor". If the only way of changing state is via acquiring a monitor (as per my example) then you're at least closer to thread safety. Again, which thread created the object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Winter synchronized method blocks "this", so Sample object itself. But synchronized block on Object "lock"  will block "lock", not the Sample

Comment: Why not just lock on the String instead of creating another object just to lock to?

Comment: @PhilipRego: Firstly, because then the value being locked on would change, which makes things unsafe in all kinds of ways. Secondly, because it could easily mean locks being unintentionally shared between multiple objects, leading to all kinds of other problems. Thirdly: separation of concerns. I'm very keen on a field having one purpose.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Would it be the same behavior if one was to use `private volatile String message = null` and `public String getMessage() {
            return message ;
    }`
?. Are there any differences between two approaches ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user2683814: Possibly, but I'd need to look *very, very* carefully at the spec to say for sure. I try not to state much about the precise semantics of `volatile` these days, as it's definitely "expert level" stuff.

Answer (score 60):

For this functionality you are better off not using a lock at all. Try an AtomicReference.

```
public class Sample {
    private final AtomicReference<String> msg = new AtomicReference<String>();

    public void setMsg(String x) {
        msg.set(x);
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg.getAndSet(null);
    }
}
```

No locks required and the code is simpler IMHO. In any case, it uses a standard construct which does what you want.

Comment: FYI there are classes in `java.util.concurrent.atomic` for primitive types such as the `AtomicBoolean` and `AtomicInteger`

Answer (score 10):

From Java 1.5 it's always a good Idea to consider java.util.concurrent package. They are the state of the art locking mechanism in java right now. The synchronize mechanism is more heavyweight that the java.util.concurrent classes.

The example would look something like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Sample {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private String message = null;

    public void newmsg(String msg) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            message = msg;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String getmsg() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            String temp = message;
            message = null;
            return temp;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), the lock should be done prior to the try block.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `synchronized` keyword.

```
class sample {
    private String msg=null;

    public synchronized void newmsg(String x){
        msg=x;
    }

    public synchronized string getmsg(){
        String temp=msg;
        msg=null;
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Using the `synchronized` keyword on the methods will require threads to obtain a lock on the instance of `sample`. Thus, if any one thread is in `newmsg()`, no other thread will be able to get a lock on the instance of `sample`, even if it were trying to invoke `getmsg()`.

On the other hand, using `synchronized` methods can become a bottleneck if your methods perform long-running operations - all threads, even if they want to invoke other methods in that object that could be interleaved, will still have to wait.

IMO, in your simple example, it's ok to use synchronized methods since you actually have two methods that should not be interleaved. However, under different circumstances, it might make more sense to have a lock object to synchronize on, as shown in Joh Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this simple example you can just put `synchronized` as a modifier after `public` in both method signatures.

More complex scenarios require other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If on another occasion you're synchronising a Collection rather than a String, perhaps you're be iterating over the collection and are worried about it mutating, Java 5 offers:

- [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)
- [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html)