# Can push notification execute code in parallel with UI thread or not?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-lifecycle

As`FirebaseMessagingService` does not use the `Main Thread`, I am just wondering as all my code in all of my activities or fragments run in `UI thread(Main Thread`). Now suppose my activity's `onCreate` method is executing and then I receive the `push notification`. Will these two blocks of code run **in parallel**, or will the push notification code wait in the queue until `onCreate()` method OR Activity's last life cycle method gets executed?

**Edit**- As you are saying code will run parallelly then suppose I have a variable in App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
    int ctr = 100;
}
```

StatusActivity.java

```
public class StatusActivity extends BaseActivity {
     public void onCreate() {
         fun();
     }
     public void fun() {
         int d = App.ctr - 1;//Step 1 Here d = 99

         int m = App.ctr - 1; // Step 3 Here m = 98

     }

}
```

FcmListener.java

```
 public class FcmListener extends FirebaseMessagingService {
     Override
     public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage mssg) {
         App.ctr = App.ctr - 1;//STEP 2 // Now App.ctr = 99

     }
 }
```

Now as you can see in the above code there will be problems if push notif code executes in parallel with `fun()`. I want `push_notif` and `fun()` to run serially, where order doesn't matter but not in parallel.

Comment: Even if it runs on the UI thread it wouldn't wait until the last lifecycle method is called.  It would post a message, and run in the order of messages posted to the handler on the UI thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan So suppose in `oncreate` I am calling a function and after that push notif arrives then now push notif code will execute in parralely with the currently calling function or not ??

Comment: It will run in parallel .it leverages on android NotificationManager to show notification .unless there is a blocking code in FirebaseMessagingService which is preventing to initiate notification, your main thread and code to show notification will run simultaneously .

Comment: @Godfather Can you see my edited code.

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you please see my edited post.

Comment: This is multithreading,one possible solution would be instead of accessing variable directly create setter getter function and use synchronized block to avoid concurrent execution.Please note it will avoid other execution so you may have to make a queue .

Comment: @Godfather Are you sure about running code parallely? Can you provide me with any source about it?

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you provide me with any source about it?

Comment: @Godfather are you there ?

Comment: @GabeSechan are you there? Can you provide me with any source about what you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in a [parallel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306419/shobhit-puri), the overriden methods of `FirebaseMessagingService` run in a background thread, so you should use synchronization strategies in order to access/use mutable object from different thread.

But the question I want to answer is a bit different. Let's for a moment assume, that overriden methods run on a main thread. So is there a possibility, that the order of execution will be `STEP 1` then `STEP 2` and then `STEP 3`?

Android works with a technique called [`MessageQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue), basically there are [`Message`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)s posted on that queue, on which [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) loops and *"parses/executes"* them.

Now if we assume, that you are currently located on `STEP 1`, it means, that there was a particular `Message` which is currently being executed (hypothetically, let's assume that action is - perform `onCreate()` of this activity).

Until this message is fully executed there cannot exist another `Message` which might get have a chance to be executed. So if we assume, that Firebase dispatches an event on background thread but the actual overriden method is being run on main thread, then this overriden method would have chance to be executed only after current `Message` (activity's `onCreate()`) has finished. In other words, there would be posted another `Message` on the `MessageQueue`, which would perform `onMessageReceived()` when the `Looper` will give chance for this message to be executed.

So, theoretically, there is no chance that the ordering would be `STEP 1` -> `STEP 2` -> `STEP 3`.

If `STEP 1` is already executed, then it will continue with `STEP 3` and the `STEP 2` (at some point in future, because you can't know what other `Message`s are already posted on `MessageQueue`).

See [this article](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/) for more details about `MessageQueue` and related classes.

Answer (score 1):

How about it?

```
class Sample {
private String message = null;
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void newMessage(String x) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        message = x;
    }
}

public String getMessage() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        String temp = message;
        message = null;
        return temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Its a bit confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents. You say,

> Suppose my activity's onCreate method is executing and then I receive the push notification. Will these two blocks of code run parallelly or will the push notification code wait in the queue until onCreate method OR Activity's last life cycle method gets executed?

From the official documentation of [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService):

> Extending this class is required to be able to handle downstream messages. It also provides functionality to automatically display notifications, and has methods that are invoked to give the status of upstream messages. Override base class methods to handle any events required by the application. **Methods are invoked on a background thread.**

So its possible both methods execute at the same time. If you want to do the operations on a shared variable in your `Application` class, you can do thread safe operations using `synchronize`. See [How to synchronize or lock upon variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5861918/1306419). That will make sure only one thread is making changes at a time on that variable. If a new thread comes in, it waits for the lock to get free and then makes the changes on that variable. However this doesn't guarantee the order. It just means that one thread operates on it at time and is in FIFO order.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a different approach, because using those global variables can lead to unexpected behavior.
If your ctr var is related to your activity, then keep it inside. If you need it on other activities consider passing it via the Intent as an extra.

Use LocalBroadcastManager to inform your activity that you received the push message

```
public class FcmListener extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = "ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage mssg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) // put extra vars as needed
        boolean delivered = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        // 'delivered' is true if there is at least someone listening to the broadcast, eg. your activity
        // If your activity is not running, then 'delivered' is false so you can act accordingly
    }
}
```

Then inside your activity

```
public class StatusActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (TextUtils.equals(FcmListener.ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, action)) {
                // do stuff with 'ctr'
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(FcmListener.ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
    }

}
```