# Can synchronized read be replaced with volatile field modifier?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

While reading the accepted answer [How to synchronize or lock upon variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861894/how-to-synchronize-or-lock-upon-variables-in-java), it occurred to me if the behavior would change if one was to use volatile in the below example instead of synchronized block. I would like to make sure message always return the correct value.

Let me use this same sample: Note now I've removed the synchronized block in the get method and marked the variable message as volatile.

```
class Sample {
    private volatile String message = null;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void newMessage(String x) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            message = x;
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Would it warrant the same behavior if one was to change the code as shown above ?. Are there any differences between two approaches ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, if it’s a single variable, then the `synchronized` block is unnecessary and a volatile write is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Are you saying I don't need synchronization at all for both read and write when the variable is marked as volatile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volatile` keyword in this case is enough because it establishes a happens-before relation for the reads and writes, guaranteeing that the write in one thread will be observed by a subsequent read in another thread.

The `synchronized` block is not incorrect but it is redundant. Also, if you do use `synchronized`, you can mark your message variable as non-volatile. But be careful and make sure the read is also in a `synchronized` block, otherwise you have a data race. Non-volatile writes made by one thread in a `synchronized` block are guaranteed to be visible for threads subsequently entering a `synchronized` block on the same monitor.

As a final note, the `synchronized` block has different progress conditions than `volatile` reads and writes. The former is blocking (mutual exclusion) while the latter is wait-free.